# Cleaning tomcat server deletes all folders at relative path

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am working on Web project in which I have created a folder named "images" under Web Contents folder in eclipse. In that folder I store images uploaded by the user and  the images are stored using relative path

"String webAppPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/images")".

But when it comes to clean tomcat server for any reason, all the folders or images stored under "images" folder get erased..

Please suggest is there any solution so that all the images or folder will not be delete.

Answer (score 0):

Two recommendations:

1. Don't use `ServletContext.getRealPath`. This is an architecturally faulty method to use. It should really be purged from the servlet specification.
2. Store your files somewhere *outside* your deployment directory, and they won't be deleted when you undeploy.

**UPDATE 2017-01-23**

In order to serve your files back to you (after uploading them), you'll need to map a part of your URL space into your application. The easiest way to do that with Tomcat 8 and later is with a resource mapper.

```
<Resources>
  <PostResources base="/real/path/to/images"
            className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
          webAppMount="/images" />
</Resources>
```

This will cause the `DefaultServlet` to serve files from your `/real/path/to/images` directory when a client requests something within the `/images` URL space.

Comment: thanku for rply...now i tried to store image under g:\workspace\Projectname\images using context path ...they remained intend but i am not able to display them in another jsp... I stored image name into database(mysql)

Comment: Please suggest me how to retrieve them

Comment: Please give an example of your JSP code. Presumably, you have an `<img>` tab somewhere. What does the `src` attribute look like?